# How do I exclude a folder from search in sublime text 3 permanently?

Tags: search, editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

is there a way to always ignore a folder... in project view.

I have multiple apps in one repo and have 'node_modules' in each app

```
mainapp
├── microapp
│   └── node_modules
├── microapp2
│   └── node_modules
├── index
├── config
└── assets
```

I want to exclude from search the `node_modules` folder when i search inside project in the above structure.

Comment: Have you tried using `folder_exclude_patterns`?

Comment: nope trying now

Comment: Follow-up question: [How do I exclude a folder from the sidebar in Sublime Text permanently, specifying it relative to the open folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71038908/4561887)

Comment: In Where input append `,<project filters>,-*/<DIR_NAME_TO_EXCLUDE>/`

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Go to the **Settings** menu and in the `Preferences.sublime-settings` file for the user and add a new node to the json named `folder_exclude_patterns`. In it, add the folders that you don't want to be displayed (in json array format).

Example:

```
{
    // ... other settings
    "folder_exclude_patterns": ["node_modules", "another_folder"],
}
```

If you want to exclude certain directory or file without hiding it from the sidebar, you can ignore the above solution and `Add Exclude Filter` in the `Where` section of the search bar. But you will have to specify it everytime you change the search directory.

*Note:* You might need to restart Sublime Text in order to see the changes, as mentioned by @Soferio

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it not only excludes these folders from search, but also from the sidebar, which isn't always desirable. I'm still looking for a reliable solution that doesn't nuke the sidebar.

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin I've updated the answer to add some of your desired solution, but it won't be a permanent one. Maybe it is possible through some third party plugins.

Comment: `-*/node_modules/*` previously did not work, but tonight it magically did. `"folder_exclude_patterns"` hides the folder from the sidebar, but not from searching :/

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55748485/4454732 for how to suppress from Find All while keeping the folders in the side bar.

Comment: Finally what really worked and excluded a vast undesirable search results was inserting `-*/node_modules/*` as suggested by @jacob. My previous search was about 20.000 files and dropped to about 80 of them.

Comment: No one has a solution for excluding the folder from search/replaces permanently? Don't wanna always have to add node_modules manually - it defeats the purpose of saving time not searching the whole node_modules ...

Comment: For me it started to work only after restarting the sublime.

Comment: [We've got it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50751326/1489243)! It's the `binary_file_patterns` array in Sublime Settings. This tells Goto Anything (⌘+T) to ignore these files. Note that the syntax is a little different as you're now matching files, not folders.

Comment: `"binary_file_patterns": ["**/node_modules/**"]` ended up working for me!

Comment: Using folder_exclude_patterns is NOT a clean solution for the OP is looking for. The fact that it hides folders from the side bar will certainly make you challenge your sanity when someday you do go looking for those files and they simply don't exist.  See my answer, below, for a better solution with `binary_file_patterns`.

Comment: Can these exclusion settings be used on a per-Sublime-workspace basis? (eg copied into a `.sublime-project` file)

Answer (score 77):

If you go to the **Preferences** menu and then select **Settings**, it will open a JSON file of all the settings and their default values. This file also serves as documentation for what the settings mean. Two of them are relevant here. Here's the snippet from the Settings JSON file (last verified in Sublime Text 4):

```json
// folder_exclude_patterns and file_exclude_patterns control which files
// are listed in folders on the side bar. These can also be set on a per-
// project basis.
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS", ".Trash", ".Trash-*"],
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", ".directory", "desktop.ini", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "*.sublime-workspace"],
// These files will still show up in the side bar, but won't be included in
// Goto Anything or Find in Files
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

It says here that `"folder_exclude_patterns"` hides it from the *side bar*, while `"binary_file_patterns"` hides it from *search* (these "won't be included in Goto Anything or Find in Files"). So if you want to exclude it from both, you can open the User Settings file, which overrides the default settings, and add the following.

*Note that the User Settings file is what you see and can edit in the right-hand pane when you go to Preferences --> Settings.*

Anyway, add the following:

```json
{
    "folder_exclude_patterns": ["node_modules"],
    "binary_file_patterns": ["*/node_modules/*"]
}
```

The two entries above are different because the former is a folder pattern while the latter is a file pattern.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, but for me it still searches node_modules/ and vendor/ it seems, number of files searched is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me, but ONLY after restarting sublime3, so don't give up....!

Comment: FWIW: this can also be applied on a per-project basis inside your `[project].sublime-project` file for each individual folder listed in there (so it should be on the same level as a `"path"` property).

Comment: @smhg, thank you thank you thank you! That's the secret! It *must* be at the same level as the `"path"` entry. I had it one level up, at the `"folders"` entry, and that doesn't work.

Comment: @smhg and anyone else wondering: there is an example of where to place `"folder_exclude_patterns"` in Project settings in the official documentation here: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/projects.html

Comment: I just wrote about [how to exclude a directory relative to the project root or open folder's root here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71039794/4561887)

Answer (score 25):

Most of the answers here focus on `folder_exclude_patterns`, and overlook that `binary_file_patterns` can specify folder patterns, probably due to its name and Sublime's default settings for it.

Using `folder_exclude_patterns` is NOT a clean solution for the OP is looking for. The fact that it hides folders from the side bar will certainly make you challenge your sanity when someday you do go looking for those files and they simply don't exist.

That concern applies also to the suppression of Find results, of course, which should be weighed carefully before blocking too many folders. Only include folders/patterns which you actively want to suppress...don't include things you simply think you won't need to search if they're not causing you problems.

---

To fix this, I went to `Sublime Text | Preferences | Settings` in the menu, found `binary_file_patterns`, and added `"node_modules/", "coverage/", "tmp/cache/"`, and `.bundle/`. For my medium-sized Ruby on Rails project, my painfully slow searches accelerated dramatically:

```
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", 
                         "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip",  
                         "node_modules/", "coverage/", "tmp/cache/", "vendor/bundle/", ".bundle/"],
```

Before, Find All In Files took about 7 seconds:

```
Searching 28526 files for "as records_with_errors"
```

After, Find All In Files takes less than 1 second:

```
Searching 1658 files for "as records_with_errors"
```

I added `coverage` not for performance, but to prevent redundant, useless search results.

Comment: For me, this still searches node_modules. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you pay that line from your config?

Comment: Sure, it's "binary_file_patterns":
 [
  "*.jpg",
  "*.jpeg",
  "*.png",
  "*.gif",
  "*.ttf",
  "*.tga",
  "*.dds",
  "*.ico",
  "*.eot",
  "*.pdf",
  "*.swf",
  "*.jar",
  "*.zip",
  "node_modules/*",
  "vendor/*",
  ".cache_loader/*"
 ],

Comment: Hmm...that seems to match what I've got locally exactly. Can you confirm it suppresses results from some of your other exclusions, such as "vendor/*" or ".pdf" ?

Comment: No, it does not exclude vendor or .pdf. Just created a file with .pdf extension and it found a string in it. Weird isnt it?

Comment: This method only works if the "Where" field in the "Find in Files" panel does not include a folder. If that field contains a directory (e.g. if you right-click in sidebar and choose "Find in Folder"), `binary_file_patterns` will not work. Here's the issue: https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/959

Comment: This was right answer. still showing on sidebar folder. but hide in search.

Answer (score 12):

To exclude any particular file (**package.json**) or any file type (**.scss**) or any sub folders (**node_modules, assets**) from a global folder search in Sublime, you can use the below notation:

```
E:\X-Author-GDocs-UI, -*/node_modules/*, -*/assets/*, -*.scss, -package.json
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a sub-folder/sub-directory `"folder_exclude_patterns": ["src/file-manager"]` worked for me on windows.