# How do I exclude a folder from the sidebar in Sublime Text permanently, specifying it relative to the open folder?

Tags: search, editor, sublimetext, text-editor

I've already read this related question ([How do I exclude a folder from search in sublime text 3 permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45423757/4561887)) but my question is different since I want to specify only the folder at the open folder's root, not a generic pattern to match at any level in the folder tree.

In Sublime Text 4 I have an open project folder via File --> "Open Folder...".

Let's say my folder layout is this:

```
mainapp
├── microapp
│   └── node_modules  <== don't exclude this (keep it)
├── microapp2
│   └── node_modules  <== don't exclude this (keep it)
├── index
├── node_modules      <=== exclude this only
├── config
└── assets
```

I'd like to exclude `mainapp/node_modules` only, NOT `mainapp/microapp/node_modules` nor `mainapp/microapp2/node_modules`. How do I do that?

I'm guessing I need to specify a `"folder_exclude_patterns"` in the settings.

Side note: why do I need to do this?
Because that folder has so much build content in it (which is constantly-changing as builds occur) that it's actually causing Sublime Text to freeze and lock up and become unusable.

Answer (score 0):

*Tested on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.*

Through sheer dumb luck and persistence with guessing, I figured it out. `//` refers to the "open folder root", apparently.

If you want to see this info about `//` added to the official Sublime Text documentation and default settings file, please upvote my [open issue on it here](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/5234).

### Update

I found some official documentation on this: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/file_patterns.html. The `//` feature was added *as of Sublime Text 4*:

> If pattern begins with `//`, it will be compared as a relative path from the project root [added in version 4.0]

My testing, however, proves that the `//` actually means "path" root, as defined below, however. So, my examples below are still correct.

### 1. If you have a folder open via File --> "Open Folder...", do this:

Preferences --> Settings --> add this `"folder_exclude_patterns"` entry to your user settings JSON file:

```json
{
    // other user settings here

    // exclude only the "mainapp/node_modules" dir
    "folder_exclude_patterns": ["//node_modules"],
    
    // other user settings here
}
```

Again, `//` means the "open folder's root".

NOTE: Changing your user settings above will apply globally to *all of your Sublime Text instances*, which may not be what you want. So, it may be better to use a "Project" instead, as described below:

### 2. If you have the folder open and saved as part of a project, do this:

Project --> Edit Project --> add this `"folder_exclude_patterns"` entry to your Project settings JSON file:

```json
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            // path to an open folder in a project
            "path": "/path/to/mainapp",

            // exclude only the "mainapp/node_modules" dir
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["//node_modules"],
        }
    ],
}
```

You can see in the official project settings file example here (https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/projects.html) that the `"folder_exclude_patterns"` entry *must* be at the same level in the JSON settings file as the `"path"` entry.

I also first learned this from [@smhg's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423757/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-from-search-in-sublime-text-3-permanently/50751326#comment124813260_50751326). Thank you!

To open another folder in your project, go to Project --> "Add Folder to Project...". Once you have multiple folders open in your project, you'll have to add multiple entries of `"folder_exclude_patterns"`, as desired, like this:

```json
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            // **absolute path** to open a folder in a project
            "path": "/path/to/mainapp",
            // exclude only the "mainapp/node_modules" dir
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["//node_modules"],
        },
        {
            // or **relative path** to open another folder in the project; 
            // the path is relative to the location of the 
            // "project_name.sublime-project" project file itself
            "path": "some_dir",
            // exclude only the "some_dir/path/to/excluded_folder" dir
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["//path/to/excluded_folder"],
        },
    ],
}
```

### Bonus: How to create a project in Sublime Text:

*To create a Project from an open folder, the steps are like this:*

1. Open a folder: File --> "Open Folder..."
2. Save it as part of a project: Project --> "Save Project As..."

   1. Now you can choose where to save your `project_name.sublime-project` file. This is the file you are editing when you go to Project --> "Edit Project" above. To open a project go to Project --> "Open Project...".

### See also:

1. Issue I opened: https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/5234
2. Comment I wrote on the Sublime Text forum: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/a-way-to-specify-root-in-project-settings/7756/4?u=ercaguy
3. Official Project settings documentation: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/projects.html. This includes:

   > Each object must have a `"path"` key, which may be relative to the project directory, or a fully qualified path.
4. [How do I exclude a folder from search in sublime text 3 permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50751326/4561887) - answer which explains how to exclude a file or folder from the *side bar* in Sublime Text, versus excluding a file or folder from *search*, such as *Goto Anything* or *Find in Files.*